# Array as function parameter - compilation error

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

I want to do a function that returns an array, for example:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "string"

using namespace std;

void minus(float v1[3], float v2[3], float v3[3][3]);

int main()
{
    float a[3] = {1,0,0};
    float b[3] = {3,2,5};
    float c[3];
    minus(a,b,c);

    cout << c[0] << "C1" << endl;
    cout << c[1] << "C2" << endl;
    cout << c[2] << "C3" << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}

void minus(float v1[3], float v2[3], float v3[3])
{
    int i;
    float aux;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        v3[i]=v1[i]-v2[i];
        return;
    }
}
```

The error is

```
[Error] cannot convert 'float*' to 'float (*)[3]' for argument '3' to 'void rectavector(float*, float*, float (*)[3])'"
```

I don't understand this error. I am returning v3 by reference.

Comment: C and C++ are completely different languages.

Comment: For this case. You can use both

Comment: Is that the only error you're getting?

Comment: @Alvaro - Here's a thought. When a person that has proven himself a C++ aficionado both on SO and away from it, tells you are wrong to clump the two languages as one, don't argue.

Comment: @Alvaro Your example wouldn't compile in C, so, no - you can't. In addition: your function takes array of an array (`float v3[3][3]`) as its 3rd parameter, but you are passing an array (`float c[3]`) to it.

Comment: And in most cases you should prefer using `std::vector` or `std::array` over raw arrays in C++

Answer (score 1):

Compilation errors always have a line number attached to them, so you know which line of code caused the problem.

*When posting, you can mark the relevant line by a comment, e.g.*

```
float c[3];
minus(a,b,c); // COMPILATION ERROR HERE
```

Assuming your compilation error is really where I guessed it is, the problem is in a mismatch between forward declaration and definition of your function:

```
void minus(float v1[3], float v2[3], float v3[3][3]);
... (some code omitted)
void minus(float v1[3], float v2[3], float v3[3])
```

Compiler examines your code from top to bottom. When it sees that your `minus` function receives `float v3[3][3]`, and you try to send it `float c[3]`, it complains.

If your compiler outputs additional error messages, you can see that it complains about the real problem - mismatch between declaration and definition - later on.